# How to get the latest values day wise from a timeseries table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, time-series

I want to get the latest values of each SIZE_TYPE day wise, ordered by TIMESTAMP. So, only 1 value of each SIZE_TYPE must be present for a given day, and that is the latest value for the day.

How do I get the desired output? I'm using PostgreSQL here.

**Input**

```
|TIMESTAMP                               |SIZE_TYPE|SIZE|
|----------------------------------------|---------|----|
|1595833641356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 07:07:21]|0        |541 |
|1595833641356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 07:07:21]|1        |743 |
|1595833641356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 07:07:21]|2        |912 |
|1595876841356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 19:07:21]|1        |714 |
|1595876841356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 19:07:21]|2        |987 |
|1595963241356 [Tue Jul 28 2020 19:07:21]|0        |498 |
|1595920041356 [Tue Jul 28 2020 07:07:21]|2        |974 |
|1595920041356 [Tue Jul 28 2020 07:07:21]|0        |512 |

*Note: the TIMESTAMP values are in UNIX time. I have given
the date-time string for reference*
```

**Output**

```
|TIMESTAMP                               |SIZE_TYPE|SIZE|
|----------------------------------------|---------|----|
|1595833641356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 07:07:21]|0        |541 |
|1595876841356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 19:07:21]|1        |714 |
|1595876841356 [Mon Jul 27 2020 19:07:21]|2        |987 |
|1595920041356 [Tue Jul 28 2020 07:07:21]|2        |974 |
|1595963241356 [Tue Jul 28 2020 19:07:21]|0        |498 |

*Note: the TIMESTAMP values are in UNIX time. I have given
the date-time string for reference*
```

**Explanation**

For July 27, the latest values for

- 0: 541 (no other entries for the day)
- 1: 714
- 2: 987

For July 28, the latest values for

- 0: 498
- 1: nothing (ignore)
- 2: 974 (no other entries for the day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (floor(timestamp / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), size_type) t.*
from input
order by floor(timestamp / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), size_type,
          timestamp desc;
```

The arithmetic is just to extract the day from the timestamp.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7919c47a31e400f49674c588033779a3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Is `floor` necessary? WIll it work fine without `floor`?

Comment: @SiddiqNx . . . If `timestamp` is an integer type, then Postgres does integer division.  So, yes it will work without `floor()`.  However, if `timestamp` is `numeric` then it will not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just want to know, if there's a way to solve this without `distinct on`. Like using subquery or window functions.

Comment: @SiddiqNx . . . Yes.  You can always replace `distinct on` with `row_number()` in a subquery.

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks. I found another way using inner join with another select query and using group by  inside it.